# Alignment of components on a web page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm very new to creating web applications so I bet that answer to this question is very simple.

On my page where I use Bootstrap, I have three rows, each of them has a `label` and a `div`. The first two `div`'s contain text field, but the third contains two `radio`s and two `labels`. The layout is not good, because the radios and labels in the third row are moved to the left and the text is a little bit higher.

[Current situation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDNs3.png)

How to add some extra space, that the beginning of the first radio button is aligned to the beginning of the text field above and in the same line as a header?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-form-label col-3 text-right">Name</label>
    <div class="col-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="${task.name}"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-form-label col-3 text-right">Description</label>
    <div class="col-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" value="${task.description}"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-form-label col-3 text-right">Finished</label>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input type="radio" id="finishedTrue" name="finished" class="custom-control-input" value="true">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="finishedTrue">True</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input type="radio" id="finishedFalse" name="finished" class="custom-control-input" value="false" checked>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="finishedFalse">False</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `padding-left: 15px` on it. Using `px-3` class ( `px-3` = `16px` ).

for more precise, you can add custom CSS using

```
.any_class {
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-form-label col-3 text-right">Name</label>
  <div class="col-7">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="${task.name}" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-form-label col-3 text-right">Description</label>
  <div class="col-7">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" value="${task.description}" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-form-label col-3 text-right">Finished</label>
  <div class="pl-3">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
      <input type="radio" id="finishedTrue" name="finished" class="custom-control-input" value="true">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="finishedTrue">True</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
      <input type="radio" id="finishedFalse" name="finished" class="custom-control-input" value="false" checked>
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="finishedFalse">False</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```